# Factorising and limits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, polynomials, factoring

How do I factorize this expression? $$(2^n-3^n+n4^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ so far I have: $$n4^n\left(\frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n-\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n +1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Forgot to mention the limits part of this question. How would I calculate the limit for this?

Comment: You have the word "limits" in the title, you should mention them in your question.

Comment: Where does factorization come into this problem? What limit are you trying to compute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how this can be factored.

For the limit,
if you take the $4^n$ out of the parens,
the expression becomes
$4(n-(3/4)^n+(1/2)^n)^{1/n}$
and this goes to 4 since
$n^{1/n} \to 1$.